# from csv to python dictionary key-list

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file like this

```
Name  Value
a     10
a     20
a     30
b     10
```

and I want a dictionary like this

```
words = { a: [10,20,30], b:[10]}
```

Sorry for the easy question

Comment: Check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
import csv

words = dict()
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter= ' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        words.setdefault(row['Name'], []).append(row['Value'])
```

Comment: Give me an error:
words.get(row['Name'], []).append(row['Value'])
KeyError: 'Name'

Comment: by default `delimiter` is `,`. if your csv is using a different `delimiter`, u can `csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')`

Comment: ok this fix the error but it returns an empty dictionary! print(words) give me {}

Comment: not working! csv using ';' as delimiter, sorry
I found a solution using two for but...

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict for this as well

```
from collections import defaultdict

some= defaultdict(list)

with open('filepath', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        x,y  = line.split(' ')
        some[x].append(y.replace('\n',''))
```